# how tho set value to “text” using Element.PropertyName IE browser?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="button" onclick = "b();" value="change" />

<script>
function b(){
    var fanme = document.getElementById('fname');
    if(fname.value){
        fname.value="";
    }else{
        fname.value="ffff";
    }
</script>
```

I tried this, but the `fname`'s value sometimes changed when I click the button twice. What's the matter?
On other browsers is OK

Comment: Does you actual code have `fanme` variable declared, not `fname`? Please use copy and paste to make sure you show the actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : instead of `Elements` use `Element` and also close function with `}`.

```
function b(){
    var fanme = document.getElementById('fname');
    if(fname.value){
        fname.value="";
    }else{
        fname.value="ffff";
    }
}
```

Comment: If your issue is solved then you should accept this because doesn't show this question in unanswered listing.

Comment: sorry for the synax error,the important is why I have to click the button twice when the fname value change?

Comment: erh...sorry,i tried sevral times and found when i click quickly the bug occured it seems that the response for click isn't in time in IE,

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="button" onclick = "b();" value="change" />

<script>
function b(){
    var fanme = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    if(fname == "" || fname == null || fname == "null"){
         fanme  = "Set the value as you want";
    }else{
         //proceed 
    }
</script>
```